# Custom method to native event object.

Tags: javascript

For quite some time I think that it is possible to add custom method to native Event object. How do you think? I have not found a way. I would be grateful for any opinions and recommendations.

Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally considered bad practice to extend the native objects of Javascript. But if you would, you add a method to the objects prototype.

Example:

html:

```
<button id="foo">Foo</button>
```

js:

```
var b = document.querySelector("#foo");

MouseEvent.prototype.foo = function () {
    alert("FOO");
};

b.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  e.foo();
};

/* for < IE9, use this instead of addEventListener...
onclick = function (e) {
  e.foo();
};
*/
```

Here you can find a list of events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event

Comment: Added a more relevant example instead.

Comment: ,What if I want to add to the already handlers -  the e.foo() ? so it will do its regular registered events + e,foo()

Comment: If you don't need support for older browsers like < IE9 then you can use `addEventListener`. This way you can add multiple handlers to the same event. I'll update the example above.

Comment: Many thanks to all speakers on the topic. The task was to create something like a live in jQuery, with a method of  Event object. I, however achieve the same effect with module pattern - variable - object with name EventDelegation and have one method - delegate. Will rewrite the script.

Comment: @bennedich Why do you need the MouseEvent....? Ive tried http://jsbin.com/ejavuy/edit#javascript,html and it worked... can you answer please ?

Comment: If you just want to use events like they are supposed to be commonly used you should not add custom methods. My example above shows you can extend the built in event classes, but it does not show any relevant implementation because I can't think of one atm. I just answered the question "Is it possible?".

Comment: @bennedich  , I was just asking... :)  +1

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom methods using Event's prototype like this:

```
Event.prototype.myFunc = function() {
    alert('My custom function!');  
};
```

and then invoke it like this:

```
document.getElementById('boo').onclick = function(event) {
    event.myFunc();
};
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rEGRr/1/